# Класс Матрица С++

Tags: c++, память, перегрузка-операторов, матрицы

Только начинаю изучать ООП, написал класс для матриц и перегрузил операторы ввода, вывода, +, -, =. Программа работает до момента с сложением матриц, а потом аварийно завершается, не могу найти ошибку, помогите пожалуйста.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


class Matrix
{
    private:
        int m;
        int n;
        int** arr;
    public:
        void Del()
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m; z++)
                delete[] arr[z];

            delete[] arr;
        }

        void Create()
        {
            arr = new int* [m];

            for (int z = 0; z < m; z++)
                arr[z] = new int[n];
        }

        void Set_Elems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    cin >> arr[i][j];
        }

        void Display()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
                }

                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        int Get_m()
        {
            return m;
        };
        int Get_n()
        {
            return n;
        };

        Matrix()
        {
            int m = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int arr = 0;
        }

        Matrix(int m, int n)
        {
            this->m = m;
            this->n = n;
            Create();
        }

        //Копирование матриц;
        void matrix_copy(const Matrix& b)
        {
            Del();
            Create();

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    arr[i][j] = b.arr[i][j];
        }

        friend Matrix operator + (Matrix& a, Matrix& b)
        {
            int m1 = a.Get_m();
            int n1 = b.Get_n();
            Matrix temp(m1, n1);

            for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++)
                {
                    temp.arr[i][j] = a.arr[i][j] + b.arr[i][j];
                }
            }

            return temp;
        }

        friend Matrix operator - (Matrix& a, Matrix& b)
        {
            int m1 = a.Get_m();
            int n1 = b.Get_n();
            Matrix temp(m1, n1);

            for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++)
                {
                    temp.arr[i][j] = a.arr[i][j] - b.arr[i][j];
                }
            }

            return temp;
        }

        Matrix operator = (const Matrix& b)
        {
            matrix_copy(b);
            return *this;
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < m; z++)
                delete[] arr[z];

            delete[] arr;
        }

};


ostream& operator <<(ostream& ostr, Matrix& m)
{
    m.Display();
    return (ostr);
}

istream& operator >>(istream& in, Matrix& m)
{
    m.Set_Elems();
    return (in);
}

int main()
{
    Matrix a(2, 2);
    cout << "Input Matrix a" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Matrix a =:" << endl;
    cout << a;
    Matrix b(2, 2);
    cout << "Input Matrix b" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Matrix b =" << endl << b << endl;
    int m1 = a.Get_m();
    int n1 = b.Get_n();
    Matrix c(m1, n1);
    c = a; // Вот здесь программа завершается
    cout << "c = a:" << c;
    c = (a + b);
    cout << "c = a + b" << c;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Matrix()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int arr = 0;
}
```

Заметим, что вы обнуляете какие-то локальные переменные, а не члены класса.

Но главное - у вас нет копирующего конструктора, а генерируемый по умолчанию выполняет поверхностное копирование. Не скажу, что это все неприятности, но этого уже достаточно...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    std::size_t m_iN = 0;
    std::size_t m_iM = 0;
    T*          m_pData = nullptr;

public:
    Matrix(std::size_t N, std::size_t M) {
        assert((N > 0) && (N > 0));
        m_pData = new T[M * N];
    }

    Matrix(Matrix& const m) {
        m_iN = m.m_iN;
        m_iM = m.m_iM;
        m_pData = new T[m_iM * m_iN];
        std::memcpy(m_pData, m.m_pData, m_iM * m_iN * sizeof(T));
    }

    Matrix& operator =(Matrix& const m) {

        if (m_pData == m.m_pData)
            return *this;

        if (m_pData != nullptr)
            delegate[] m_pData; 

        this(m);    
        return *this;
    }
    ~Matrix() {
        if (m_pData != nullptr)
            delete[] m_pData;

    }

    auto operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const noexcept->T {
        assert((i < m_iN) && (j < m_iM));
        return m_pData[i*m_iN + m_iM];
    };

    auto operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const noexcept->T& {
        return m_pData[i*m_iN + m_iM];
    }
```

};

В твоем случае наверняка ты где-то удаляешь по NULL укзателю и из-за этого программа падает. Сделай проверку при удалении